# Bootstrap 4 : How to force tab-navigation to stay in place?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4 tab navigation, every tab click jumps to the right tab pane but doesn't stay where it should be.

If the pane is too long for the viewport, it jumps to the top of the page after load, masking the nav-tabs. I came across some bootstrap 3 solutions but can't find any for bootstrap 4.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I found this piece of code, removing it should do the trick

```
/*========== SMOOTH SCROLLING TO LINKS ==========*/

$(document).ready(function(){ //document is loaded
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {//click on any link;anchor tag;

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") { //for e.g. website.com#home - #home
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;
      //console.log('hash:',hash)

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({ //animate whole html and body elements
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top //scroll to the element with that hash
      }, 800, function(){ // speed of animation

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash; //website.com - website.com#home
        //Optional remove "window.location.hash = hash;" to prevent transparent navbar on load
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much daviddd. In fact, I just had to comment the last line : //window.location.hash = hash;

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine in Bootstrap 4 too. It might be issue with your css or some piece of code. [check here about tab-pane](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_nav_tabs_toggleable&stacked=h)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
         <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>  <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
      </div>
      <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
          <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>  <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```